# Error - Ruby On Rails - syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Ruby on Rails from Code4Startup. This piece of code was copied from the complete code, which you can check right below. This portion of code is causing an error:

"syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input"
"Extracted source (around line #104): 
102 "< /html >"

```
  <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
     <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
      <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown2"><%= current_user.email %> <i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a></li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Now if I remove this code, It works. I don´t know what is wrong, or even if this piece of code is affecting other parts of the code.

**Complete Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Code4Pro</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>


<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">My Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">My Courses</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
</ul>        

<ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">My Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">My Courses</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
 <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
</ul>     

<header>
     <nav class="brown lighten-4 z-depth-2">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Code4Pro</a>
          <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
            <% if(!user_signed_in?) %>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
            <% else %>
             <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
              <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1"><%= current_user.email %> <i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a></li>
              <% end %>
          </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
    </nav>
          </ul>
          <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
             <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
              <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown2"><%= current_user.email %> <i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a></li>
              <% end %>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>    
</header>

    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

<main>
        <div class="container">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
</main>

<footer class="page-footer brown lighten-4">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col l6 s12">
                <h5 class="white-text">Code4Pro</h5>
                <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
                <h5 class="white-text">Social</h5>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Twitter</a></li>
                  <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Facebook</a></li>
                  <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Google Plus</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-copyright">
            <div class="container">
            © 2015 Copyright Haruo
            <%= link_to "About us", pages_about_path, :class => "" %> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>


</body>

<script>
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
$(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
</script>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `<% end %>` code doesn't look like it is ending anything.

You could delete it, but judging by the full code sample you posted, the intention may be to do this:

```
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
        <% if(!user_signed_in?) %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
         <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
        <% else %>
          <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown2"><%= current_user.email %> <i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a></li>
        <% end %>
```

That is, create a conditional for: "if user is not logged in" display registration/log in links "else" activate dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got an `<% end %>` tag without a block opening it, so if you remove it you should be good.

```
 <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown2"><%= current_user.email %> <i class="mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a></li>
   <% end %>
```